# Enabling SNMP in android device

Tags: android, networking, snmp

I am doing this snmp project in android. what i would like to know is how to enable snmp in android device. To enable snmp in windows etc. there are some steps, for eg:
https://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/help/appendix/snmp-agent-configuration.html

Similar to this, is there any way to enable it in android.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: SNMP is really old school. I'd put it in the same category as "NIS/yellow pages", from the old times when Sun/Solaris where kings. Are you sure you really want to do this? Is this a product requirement? Does not sounds to me as a very interesting project...

Comment: SNMP is old school, but it is still the best network management protocol. So, is it possible to enable it in android?